# RTE + Video (flash <embed> or <video>)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I imported news from an old tt_news extension into the new tx_news extension.
Some of this news had a video in it with this code:

```
<embed quality="high" base="http://www.domain.com/" flashvars="width=480&height=320&file=http://www.domain.com/fileadmin/media/Videos/Video.mp4&autostart=false&image=http://www.domain.com/fileadmin/media/Videos/video.jpg&controlbar=over&fullscreen=true" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" style="WIDTH: 480px; HEIGHT: 320px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.domain.com/typo3conf/ext/flvplayer2/pi1/mediaplayer.swf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" height="320" width="480" title="Adobe Flash Player" />
```

When I watch at one of this news now, this code is outputted as text. 

So I added the following typoscript to my templates setup.txt (and to test also to constants.txt and in the properties of the rootpage into the Ressources->Page TSConfig):

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTags := addToList(embed)
```

But it does not change anything. When I edit this news in the backend and put this code into the RTE-HTML-Mode and go back to the WYSIWYG-Mode I see the video until I save the news. Then its back as text. It changes `<` to `&lt;` and so on.

I also tried to replace the embed flash video with a html5-video element. For that I added video to the allowed tags:

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTags := addToList(embed, video)
```

And added this html into the RTE-HTML-Mode.

```
<div class="video" id="videoXX">
    <video controls="controls" poster="poster.jpg" width="auto" height="auto">
        <!-- .mp4 file for native playback in IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and most mobile browsers -->
         <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
    </video>
</div>
```

So I guess the typoscript is wrong (or on the wrong place?) but I can not figure out what would be the right typoscript to allow the embed and video tag.

Also, is it possible to not parse the RTE at all? What I put into the HTML-Mode is always what I want and I do not want that to get parsed at all.

 If that is possible I think that would solve all my problems with RTE, if not can someone help me find the right typoscript and/or place to put that typoscript in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working example with iframe. I made the following settings (*iframe is replaced with video to fit to your question*):

in a PageTS:

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(video, source)
RTE.default.proc.allowTags := addToList(video, source)
```

and in a Setup TypoScript:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    allowTags := addToList(video, source)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a bit strange that I need the Typoscript in Setup and in PageTS. For Video the `source` tag needs to be added too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I extended the answer with the source option, if someone find yor question in the future. :)